# JavaScript - Replace a string with anchor tag while fetching data from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have encountered this problem while doing loop over array of objects. Consider I have below array of objects.

```
General : [
       {
          question: 'Whats you suggestion?',
          answer: "Before you go ahead and book one of our trusted developer, please read our FAQ.",
       },
       {
          question: 'Do you have guaranteed solution?',
          answer: 'Please let us know at hello@stackoverflow.com.',
       }
     ]
```

I am using `map` in my `JSX` (react application) something like this.

```
General.map((faq, index) => (
        <details>
          <summary>{faq.question}</summary>
          <div>
            <Linkify>{faq.answer}</Linkify>
          </div>
        </details>
      ))}
```

Now I want the text `hello@stackoverflow.com` to render as `html` anchor tag. I have done this through [React Linkify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkify). But how we can achieve this with pure javascript ?

Comment: You can do it by trying it yourself, and then if your attempt does not succeed, asking for further assistance. Stack Overflow does not exist to write your code for you.

Comment: @IanKemp believe me I did, I tried to split the sting, replace it with desired anchor tag, but it treat it as string not plain text.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for emails, but you'll need to work out the regex for urls and chain them. Hope it helps.

```
General.map((faq, index) => {
  const emailRegex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/g;
  const emailReplacer = "<a href='mailto:$1'>$1</a>";
  return (
    <details>
      <summary>{faq.question}</summary>
      <div>
        <div>
          {faq.answer.replace(emailRegex, emailReplacer)}
        </div>
      </div>
    </details>
  )
})
```